# SQL LIKE Operator with hash

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have problem with my query.
Mysql:

```
------------------------------------
| id | string                      |
------------------------------------
|  1 | people#-#car#-#music#-#art  |
|  2 | music#-#sport#-#cars        |
|  3 | photography#-#sport#-#art   |
|  4 | car#-#peoples#-#photography |
|  5 | music#-#games#-#sport       |
 ....
------------------------------------
```

I want to find all items with (for. example) specific word `people`

Now when i do:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `components` 

WHERE 

    lower(string) LIKE '%$word%'
```

will find:

```
------------------------------------
| id | string                      |
------------------------------------
|  1 | people#-#car#-#music#-#art  |
|  4 | car#-#peoples#-#photography |
 ....
------------------------------------
```

But I need to find only a specific word. In my case `(id4)` `peoples` does not fit. And my solution does not work ...

```
SELECT `id` FROM `components` 

WHERE

    lower(string) = '$word'

    OR

    lower(string) LIKE '$word#-#%'

    OR

    lower(string) LIKE '%#-#$word'

    OR

    lower(string) LIKE '%#-#$word#-#%'
```

In this case, I do not have any result. What am I doing wrong? Good thinking?
I ask for advice. Is hash in a string a bad solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `components` 
WHERE concat('#', string, '#') like concat('%#', $word, '#%);
```

The correct approach is to not store lists of things as strings.  SQL has a great structure for storing lists -- it is called a table.  You should have a table like `ComponentWords` with one row for each component and word.

Comment: new function, thank u. Additionally I had an error in the string (space) `people #-#car#-#music#-#art`. And i think that second concat() function should be: `concat('%#', '$word', '#%')`

Comment: @PediGonzalez . . . The comma was a typo.  If you have problems with spaces, you can use `concat('#', replace(string, ' ', ''), '#') like . . . `